# Scroll even if covered by absolute-positioned element (slimscroll) – jsfiddle included

Tags: jquery, scroll, mouseover, mousewheel, slimscroll

So, slimScroll.js is basically a plugin that disables native browser scrolling and instead enables a nice scrollbar. When your mouse is hovered over a slimScroll container, it will allow you to use your mousewheel to scroll inside.

However, I have a fixed/absolute positioned element covering a portion of the slimScroll container, so if the mouse is over this fixed/absolute element, it will not allow you to scroll in the container.

I want to be able to scroll even when hovered over the fixed/absolute positioned element, as long as it is above the slimScroll container.

I have tried with mouseOver but haven't managed to get anywhere in a few days, and wonder if anyone could shed any light. I've made a jsFiddle with all the code so you can see what the problem is. (try scrolling your mousewheel when your mouse is over the #scroll-over element.)

```
<div id="scroll-over" style="position:fixed;">
</div>

<div id="slimtest1">
content
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kfmz58q5/2/

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `pointer-events: none` like so:

```
#scroll-over {
    pointer-events: none;
}

#scroll-over a {
    pointer-events: auto;
}
```

The second solution would be to put the `#scroll-over` div inside `#slimtest1`. That way, you wouldn't need pointer events and you can achieve what you want.

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately that won't work for me because there will be links in the fixed/absolute div: see here: http://jsfiddle.net/kfmz58q5/2/

Comment: There are many links in the overlay div... it won't work well for UX. if the mouse is over a link and user tries to scroll it wont work :( really Im looking to modify the jquery to allow scrolling when the mouse is over the div in question.

Comment: @caustic I updated my answer. I found that the solution would be to put the header inside the scrolling content. That way, you can achieve what you want.

Comment: Yes, it can be achieved that way but unfortunately I need the div outside the box lol :/